# Delaying addClass jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a sticky nav on scroll with a header above which shrinks. Now I'm trying to get the logo to come in from the left when the nav becomes sticky. It works but its coming in too early. If you have a look at my demo you can see that it comes in over the header which I don't want. Is there any way I can delay it coming in until the nav is fixed to the top?

demo: https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/xqaEZX

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $("header").addClass("shrink");
    //setTimeout(function(){
    $(".logo_animated").addClass("logo_display");
    //}, 900);
  } else {
    $("header").removeClass("shrink");
    $(".logo_animated").removeClass("logo_display");
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#head-background {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

header {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 322px;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.address-info {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.head-icons {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.head-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

.head-icons li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.head-icons li:nth-child(4) {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.shrink {
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #777;
  font-size: 0;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.burger-button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: none;
}

.logo_animated {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  margin-left: -20rem;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.6);
}

.logo_display {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

#body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head-background">
  <header>
    <h4 class="address-info">00 The Street<br>Bramhope<br>Leeds<br>LS00 000</h4>
    <img class="image" src="images/PopsiesLogoWhite.png">
    <ul class="head-icons">
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="mailto:popsiesfishandchips@yahoo.co.uk"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li>0113 1234567</li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <img class="logo_animated" src="images/popsies.svg">
    <div class="burger-button">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <ul id="height">
      <li><a href="#welcomeAnchor">Welcome</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menuAnchor">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#timesAnchor">Opening Times</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="body"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Jquery has built in function delay() which allow to organize delaying between effects showing

Comment: You've already got a settimeout but you commented it out?

Comment: I tried using the settimeout but when I scrolled back to the top the logo stayed in the top until I scrolled down a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this without any delays or adding/removing two classes. Using hardcoded delay is actually a bad practice. If you tweak how your CSS is inherited you can do this like so:

> Here's the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evLdoy) and relevant code below:

1. Add `.shrink` to `#head-background` element in JS, and apply the rule in css like:

```css
 #head-background.shrink header{
      height: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

2. Decleare your `.logo_animated` class like so:

```css
#head-background.shrink .logo_animated {//apply this rule only when #head-background has .shrink class too. 
      margin-left: 1rem;
      transition: margin-left .8s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.6);
    }
```

Your JavaScript will now only look like:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $("#head-background").addClass("shrink");
  } else {
    $("#head-background").removeClass("shrink");
  }

});
```

Notice how you don't need to add/remove `.logo_display` class separately, its now achieved by css inheritance.

Here's how this works:

You apply shrink class to the parent of both `head` and `.logo_animated`. Then you setup a selector `#head-background.shrink .logo_animated` which tells the browser to only apply rule after the `.shrink` class has been applied to the parent. Which essentially gives you the desired effect. Remember you still have to tweak the animation time properly. In codepen example I used `.8s` for `.logo_animated`. You can further refine your animation now to make it look smoother, I basically left it at what you had

Comment: Didn't think I could achieve it like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a time delay?  Here's the JS snippet:

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
         // your function here
}, 300);
```

set the milliseconds accordingly, I put in 300, change it to what you need.

I went to your demo and tested this and it works.  The "if" statement wasn't in the right place:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
setTimeout(function(){
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20) {
   $("header").addClass("shrink");
      $(".logo_animated").addClass("logo_display");
     } else {
   $("header").removeClass("shrink");
   $(".logo_animated").removeClass("logo_display");
}} , 900);
});
```

Comment: I tried using this function but when I scrolled back to the top the logo stays there. Look at my demo and uncomment that function you'll see what I mean. Maybe I'm using it wrong

Comment: Please review the update I made, I went to your demo and it tested properly.

Comment: Using hardcoded delay like that is always a bad idea, especially when you can do this without any delays and without having to separately add/remove .logo_display class. Please check my answer/

Comment: Agreed, to a point, CSS solution depends on different browsers and other possible dependency issues where that solution may not work, which is why perhaps the question was "DELAYING addClass jQuery", which is exactly what setTimeout does.  Also, your solution doesn't implement a delay, which is what this developer specifically asked for as I didn't think it was my place to assume I fully understand his/her's context or situation.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aaron stated. Uncomment the `setTimeout`.

Or use a CSS solution. You can delay any `transition` with this simply property:

```
transition-delay: 0.9s;
```

So in your case. Make the following class in your css file like this:

```
.logo_display {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    transition-delay: 0.9s;
}
```

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $("header").addClass("shrink");
    //setTimeout(function(){
    $(".logo_animated").addClass("logo_display");
    //}, 900);
  } else {
    $("header").removeClass("shrink");
    $(".logo_animated").removeClass("logo_display");
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/****************************************
****************HEADER*******************
****************************************/

#head-background {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

header {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 322px;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.address-info {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.head-icons {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.head-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

.head-icons li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.head-icons li:nth-child(4) {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.shrink {
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/****************************************
**************NAVIGATION*****************
****************************************/

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #777;
  font-size: 0;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/****************************************
********STICKY NAVIGATION****************
****************************************/

.burger-button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: none;
}

.logo_animated {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  margin-left: -20rem;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.6);
}

.logo_display {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
}

#body{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="head-background">
    <header>
      <h4 class="address-info">00 The Street<br>Bramhope<br>Leeds<br>LS00 000</h4>
      <img class="image" src="images/PopsiesLogoWhite.png">
      <ul class="head-icons">
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <!--
                 -->
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <!--
                 -->
        <li><a href="mailto:popsiesfishandchips@yahoo.co.uk"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <!--
                 -->
        <li>0113 1234567</li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <nav>
      <img class="logo_animated" src="images/popsies.svg">

      <div class="burger-button">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <!--

             -->
      <ul id="height">
        <li><a href="#welcomeAnchor">Welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menuAnchor">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#timesAnchor">Opening Times</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
  <div id="body">
    
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: transition delay doesn't do what I really need. As for the setTimeout function see my reply to arron. Thanks

Comment: @Reece Be more specific. What exacly doens't it do, which you want it to do?

Comment: @Reece I think i figured it out for you. Add `transition-delay: 0.9s;` that property to `.logo-display` I thnk thats exacly what you want isnt it?

Comment: using hard-coded delays is bad idea, especially when this can be solved using proper css-inheritance and animation.

Comment: @Shaunak source for that? Cuse ive never heard that `transition-delay` is a bad thing?

Comment: Exactly my point. Either is bad, as it can be dependent on browsers and rendering speeds. Especially when you can do this without either, transition-delay or setTimeout.